# Vbscript seek to end of file to make a tail command script

Tags: vbscript

I've writen a simple tail command using vbscript.  It works fine except for very large files where it has to read through the entire file to get the last 10 lines.  Is there a way to seek to the end of the file and then read backwards for ten lines?

Comment: It may be possible for you to use the Microsoft text drivers : `strcon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Docs\;"
strcon = strcon & "Extended Properties=""Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"` You can then select a specific position quite quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that seeking backwards is impossible in VBS TextStream, but instead of reading through the entire file you can seek to a position eg. 1K before EOF and then read the rest of the file, displaying only the last 10 lines.

EDIT: I'm adding some sample code to illustrate the idea:

```
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set file = fso.GetFile(filePath)
set stream = file.OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
pos1KBeforeEnd = file.Size-1024
if pos1KBeforeEnd<0 then pos1KBeforeEnd=0
stream.Skip pos1KBeforeEnd
```

Comment: Would that be using the Skip method? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265375(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: And use the File.Size property.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I modified the answer and added some sample code.

Comment: My file is about 24 gig and stream.skip throws an overflow error.  Oh Well.

Comment: I do not have such a big text file by hand, so I can not test this idea, but maybe skipping in several 1 gig jumps would do?