# Retrieving last line of a txt file with a VBscript

Tags: string, text, vbscript, text-files

Before all, I want to say that I am not a programmer, so this may be basic for some people but surely not for me!!

The task that I want to accomplish is to retrieve some characters of a data file that is imported automatically from a server.
Data is stored in lines in a CSV or tabbed .txt file, each line consists of date and some numeric values. The format is always the same, only the file grows in one line each time a new value is entered.

What I need the script to do, is open that file (wich adress is known and constant) search for the last line, and then extract a string from that line and write it on a different .TXT file, from where I can import it to another specific software as a raw value.

The part in the middle (extracting string) is fairly simple, but opening and isolating the last line is far too much for me.

Thanks everybody for helping!

Comment: The only way is to read line by line and grab the last one.

Comment: You do not have to read the file line by line. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577628/vbscript-seek-to-end-of-file-to-make-a-tail-command-script/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dim path 
path = "fileName.txt"
otherOption(path)
function otherOption(fileName)
    const read = 1
    dim arrFileLines()

    set objArgs = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject")
    if objArgs.FileExists(fileName) then
        set objFile = objArgs.OpenTextFile(fileName,read)
        i=0
        do until objFile.AtEndOfStream          
            redim preserve arrFileLines(i)      
            arrFileLines(i) = objFile.ReadLine  
            i = i + 1                           
        loop
        objFile.Close
    end if  
    wscript.Echo arrFileLines(i-1)
end function
```